# custom density function with fitdistrplus

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

Is it possible to use fitdistrplus to fit custom density functions?

For example:

How to estimate the parameters from the following density function?

[image]

Comment: This question might generate less negativity if you edited it to show that you have actually read the help page for `fitdistrplus` and the vignette that comes with the package. The help page makes it clear that you need more than just a density function. Unfortunately, at the moment it appears that you just want us to do your statistics homework for you. You can correct that impression by putting in code that demonstrates effort.

Comment: user 42, let me try to change the impression that I caused to you.

I have no, or at least a small, background in statistics.

Comment: fandreacci, does the above equation correlate to a named distribution (I know it's not normal, lognormal, but is it something else that might be a named function)?

Comment: I already got good fits by weibull and lognormal functions. However, I found a not know functions, called WEBER, which I would like to try. WEBER function seems to be appropriate to my data, However, I have no idea on how to make it. Since user friendly softwares do not have WEBER functions, I'm trying to find alternatives.

Comment: greengrass62
WEBER

https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjD3pyOs9PMAhVH1R4KHS62AnAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdspace.c3sl.ufpr.br%2Fdspace%2Fbitstream%2F1884%2F12720%2F1%2FSAULO%2520HENRIQUE%2520WEBER.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHji36ahkFAD8Zff1FVjMZoczEPLg&bvm=bv.121926005,d.dmo

sorry, but I found no english descriptions about it.

Comment: look at gamma. if weibull and lognormal are candidates, gamma is likely a good one also. However, look at ?fitdist, and look at example #4. They show example of gumbel in a user created function and then used with fitdist

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. Thank you!